# Problem with knit to html in pandoc and RGL

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, rgl

I'm trying to export my code with the rmarkdown to html. I'm work with geometric morphometrics analysis with geomorph package. Among my plots, I have some 3D models that are plotted with the RGL. The errors that are happening:

```
pandoc.exe: Out of memory
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 251
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rgl.snapshot(...) :
  RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
2: In rgl.snapshot(...) :
  RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
3: In rgl.snapshot(...) : RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Error: Invalid IHDR data
4: In rgl.snapshot(...) : RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Error: an error occured
5: In rgl.snapshot(...) : 'rgl.snapshot' failed
```

The code that isn't working is:

```
#Creating mesh
require(knitr,quietly = T)
require(abind,quietly = T)
afflongiseta.mand.ldk<-read.morphologika(filelist = "afflongiseta_w.txt")
dimnames(afflongiseta.mand.ldk)[[3]][1]<-"afflongiseta_w"
afflongiseta.mand<-read.ply("afflongiseta_w.ply",ShowSpecimen = F)
m.w.mand<-mshape(mand.w.gpa$coords)
m.longiseta.mand<-warpRefMesh(mesh = afflongiseta.mand,mesh.coord = afflongiseta.mand.ldk[,,1],ref = m.w.mand)
```

```
#Ploting PC1 minor
require(knitr,quietly = T)
require(abind,quietly = T)
knit_hooks$set(webGL = hook_webgl)
PC1.w.mand<-plotTangentSpace(mand.w.gpa$coords, warpgrids = T, mesh=m.longiseta.mand, label = class.mand.w$Species, axis1 = 1,axis2 = 2)
```

My pandoc version is 1.19.2.1

Comment: You need to post the code that doesn't work if you want help with it.  Don't post your whole document, just a minimal example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: also try updating your pandoc version...

Comment: I put the information in the post

Comment: Don't use `hook_webgl`.  Call `rgl::rglwidget()` after doing your plot.